# Maintaining times with points2one in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, time

I have a problem that might be trivial, but I really cannot find a solution!

I have a csv files with several points (x,y).

These points represent the position of different animals at different times, and thus can be joined in several tracks (each point belongs to a single track, but a track can have from 2 to several points). Now these points have clearly also a time, but if I join them using Points2one I loose this information that I need to calculate the speed of the animals.

Is there a way to have a multime time column (or at least first-last time) or to calculate the speed of an animal if I have such dataset?

Comment: have you considered  postgis ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have only limited knowledge of gis in general, and I don't know either postgis nor python. My problem, I know!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your question yourself: Points2one cannot do it by default. Since it's a Python plugin, you could easily extend it to calculate the aggregates you want if you know Python.

There are other workarounds which include other plugins and more steps. Are you interested in those?

This could also be a good exercise to develop a Processing tool. Again, are you interested in this path?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't know Python, so I would love to know another workaround with more steps.